# Two cards are drawn without replacement. Find the probability the second card is a jack given the first is not a jack.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

My calculations:

I got $\frac{4}{51}$ because there are $4$ jacks in a deck and if we didn't have a jack then there are still $4$ left out of $51$ because we already chose one card.

Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after the first card is taken out there are 51 cards. Of these 51 cards there are 4 jacks. Therefore the probability you get a jack is 4/51 as you said.

This comes from the definition of [probability spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space#Definition). The important one is the one that says that they are countably additive. Let $J_1,J_2,J_3, J_4$ be the four jacks. Since the probability of each card is 1/51 then $P({J_1})=P(J_2)=P(J_3)=P(J_4)=\frac{1}{51}$ and therefore $P\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^4  {{J_i}}=\frac{1}{51}*{4}=\frac{4}{51}$

Comment: typo: $\operatorname{P}(J_1)=\frac{1}{51}$ (no jokers)

Comment: yes, thank you for that

Answer (score 1):

That is correct if there were no jokers in your deck.

More formally:
Let $A_i$ be the event that the $i$-th card is a jack.

\begin{align}
\Pr[A_2|\overline{A_1}] &=\frac{\Pr[A_2\overline{A_1}]}{\Pr[\overline{A_1}]} \\
&= \frac{48\times 4}{2!\binom{52}{2}}\div\frac{48}{52}\\
&=\frac{4}{51}
\end{align}